# How are LEGO bricks packaged?

Tags: manufacturing

This week I got a LEGO set gifted and while I was building and unpacking I thought about how the single pieces might come in their respective little bags? I had some fun fantasizing to the point where I'd really like to see the packaging machine.

Id love a video "how its made" style but I only found some on youtube from a LEGO HQ tour showing molding and storage but not the step for pieces from storage to package.

So does anybody know this? :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a comprehensive walk-through:

http://gizmodo.com/exclusive-look-inside-the-lego-factory-5022769

The last video shows how parts are retrieved from the shelves, decorated, packaged in plastic bags and put into set boxes. It is probably exactly how you imagined the process :)

Answer (score 0):

The pieces are counted by weight, and placed into the bags which are then heat-sealed. If you are looking for a video, I can recommend one, it doesn't go too far in depth on how the pieces themselves are packaged, although that is part of it (skip to 33:26), but this documentary is certainly a good watch for anyone interested in the manufacturing of Lego:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zZjEuoPkLY

If you watch How It's Made, there are many on products with similar packaging processes.